# PHP - How to read the importance (low normal high) on a imap server

Tags: php, imap

I've been playing with the PHP's awesome imap capabilities.. I'm curious how I can read the importance level of an email.. is there a way to get which email was sent as High?

Thank you!

-Henry

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `imap_headerinfo()` function to get the header of a message and you can read the importance of message by reading header info.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-headerinfo.php

Comment: i've looked at that - there is no priority data that i can see.. can you give any more details? otherwise I'm thinking of using imap_fetchbody  and just parsing? but that can be messy

Comment: ok if you have outlook, go into the message try to read the header in ms outlook first

Answer (score 0):

Call `imap_fetchheader()`.  Explode the header on '\n', then massage the resulting data by joining any of the resulting lines that begin with a space or tab character back into the previous line (RFC 5322 header folding).

You'll want the values of the `Importance` and `X-Priority` headers.  An `X-Priority` of "1" or "2" translates into high importance; a value of "4" or "5" is low importance.  Likewise, an `Importance` of "high" or "low" should be self-explanatory.